# iOS devices randomly receive push notifications

Tags: c#, ios, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure mobile service which simply sends push to Android and iOS devices.
It works perfectly when I use my certificate in sandbox mode. However, when I use my production one, I randomly receive a push only once in four or five tries.

Here is the code I use, it's fairly simple:

```
 ApplePushMessage appleMessage = new ApplePushMessage(content, TimeSpan.FromHours(8));

 var appleResult = await Services.Push.SendAsync(appleMessage);
 Services.Log.Info(appleResult.State.ToString());
```

The state I receive from Azure is "Enqueued" so I guess it's alright.

I've tried several devices on several iOS versions, with different network connections, without a difference.
Am I doing something the wrong way?
Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure, you're testing the production server with the production keys on a device that received the application from an ad-hoc delivery, right? The production server doesn't work when the app is delivered to the phone from XCode using a USB cable

Comment: Actualy, I'm deploying In-House Applications Over the Air. Besides, notifications work once in a while, so I guess this is something else.